# Installing SSL in NodeJS (didn't send any data, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, xampp

I have downloaded a SSL certificate that I have recieved from app.zerossl.com and placed it in the same directory as my main node script; and have used this code to install it.

```
var fs = require('fs');

let options = {
 cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certificate.crt'),
 ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/ca_bundle.crt'),
 key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/private.key')
};
```

My configuration for running the server is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Now i'm running MYSQL and PHP on XAMPP with the port set to 1337. In my modem i've set the DMZ to my Computer/Servers' internal IP Address. When I try to access my domain over the internet it comes up with an error. (didn't send any data, ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) assumingly from my Node JS server.

Now when I go on the https version of my website using the address bar, it comes up with a warning then redirects to my XAMPP server. The port is not set on the address bar, so i'm not sure why it's redirecting to the XAMPP server.

I'm wondering why isn't my SSL working and why is it redirecting to my XAMPP server instead of using the NodeJS server when I place in https?

Comment: How did you setup port in xampp, can you provide XAMPP>apache>conf>httpd.conf output to see how your port and IP are set to listen, make sure to redact the IP and port before sharing? Also, try the express server without SSL at first to make sure you have the external connection done properly. Then after that you can debug the SSL part.

Comment: XAMPP>apache>conf>httpd.conf is set to listen to port 1337. The server works without the https and with the http module. When I change it to the https module it doesnt work and when I access it via https the xampp server loads instead of the node js server.

Comment: Ah, I'll just redirect the xampp server to the http version of the website for now. =_=
I have no idea what will happen when I try to install https on the node js server since the https version just goes to the XAMPP server anyways.

Comment: recommending to use something like nginx since the setup is requiring to host two servers and one public IP entry point. You can see more details in the answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running two servers and one public entry point, then you will need to use something like nginx to be able to access both from your external IP.

XAMPP is probably taking priority over the express server which is why is going there.

NOTE: If you are dealing with HTTPS, make sure to add router rule to utilize port 443.

Here are some docs on how to host two servers in one. In this case, it's two websites but you can change it to make it works for one website and one backend server since this is specifically for routing to different ports.

NOTE: You can skip server_name and just add the port forward in each configuration. This way you can have one port forward to 1337 for your xampp, and another port for your express server.

[https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-configure-nginx-to-serve-multiple-websites-single-vps#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20a,to%20host%20all%20your%20domains](https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/how-configure-nginx-to-serve-multiple-websites-single-vps#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20a,to%20host%20all%20your%20domains).

Comment: You were correct, XAMPP was taking priority over the express server.